# passport.js LocalStrategy AJAX login and authentication not working

Tags: passport.js, express-session

Trying to use passport.js with ajax login screen.

Using express-session for session store and this is all working OK for other strategies ie OIDC.

After doing some research my code looks like this.

COnfigure:

```
export function configure(passport) {
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "password",
      },
      async (email, password, done) => {
        try {
          const response = await postAPI(
            "auth/authenticate",
            { email, password },
            null,
            null,
            true
          );

          if (response.ok) {
            // got authenticated user
            return done(null, response.data);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, {
              message: "Invalid login credentials",
            });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          return done(null, false, {
            message: "Login failed",
          });
        }
      }
    )
  );
}
```

Login route:

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err || !user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ info });
    } else {
      return res.status(200).json({ user });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

The flow all seems to work OK for authentication success and fail with correct responses to client but for the successful authentication path, the session isn't being setup up ie no passport object in req.session and it looks like an unauthenticated session so user is being sent back to login by the isAuthenticated() check.

What am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

OK worked it out. For this approach with local strategy, need to add:-

```
req.logIn(user, callback)
```

to the successful authentication path to set up the session